# Sync failed - Error about DatabindingBuilder

Tags: java, android

Why isn't my project running when I click on "`run`"?

I get this panel:

[image]

> BUILD.GRADLE:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.materialtabs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile files('libs/tinydb-0.0.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/droidText.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jipsi.jar')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    //    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'net.gotev:uploadservice:2.1'
    compile files('libs/jipsi_055b734e299151494aa487f8b477464882efb509.jar')
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

AND

> LOGCAT

[image]

Comment: have you tried closing project and reimporting importing the project?

Comment: you can check in your message window about the error for more specific info...

Comment: i got this : Error:(1, 0) android/databinding/tool/DataBindingBuilder
<a href="openFile:/Users/marco/Downloads/MaterialTabs/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Share your build.gradle and also the logcat

Comment: @MalikAhsan i added gradle and logcat

Comment: can you check following with your project level build.gradle : 

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // <=== *** Adding this fixed it ***
    }

Comment: Also share project level build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your project level build.gradle jcenter () is added like this

```
allprojects { repositories { mavenCentral()  jcenter() }}
```

Also check this

[Gradle couldn't find com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675787/gradle-couldnt-find-com-android-databindingdatabinder1-0-rc0)

This will be of help to you.